# xor command causing "Memory Address out of bounds" Error in Mips

Tags: assembly, mips

I have to print an xor of two numbers. However, when I try to achieve this, I get a "Memory Address out of Bounds". What's going wrong?

Here's the code:

```
.data
first: .asciiz "0 xor 0 is "
zero: .word 0
one: .word 1

.text
main:

li $v0, 4
la $a0, first
syscall #print first

li $v0, 4
la $a1, zero
la $a2, zero
xor $a0, $a1, $a2
syscall #print 0 xor 0

li $v0, 10
syscall #exit
```

When it prints it out in the command prompt, I get this:

```
0 xor 0 is Memory Address out of Bounds
```

Why am I getting that error?

Answer (score 2):

I have figured it out, I was using

```
la $v0, 4
```

Instead of what I should be using to print integers:

```
la $v0, 1
```

Comment: I assume you mean `li` not `la`